# Possible to recreate MobileSafari's back button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, uitoolbar

I'm currently working on a UIWebView and am struggling to understand how Apple were able to create the left and right pointing buttons in their UIToolbar in MobileSafari.

Sure, we are able to use the "UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay" as the right pointing arrow, but how do I go about creating the left arrow?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also possible to create bar button items with custom images. Just create an image of a left-pointing arrow and init the bar button item with `-initWithImage:style:target:action:`.

Comment: Is it possible to do so without a custom image or is the only way to go with one?

Comment: @the0rkus: you can read the list of system-provided buttons as well as I can: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW41